# Deduce something is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have been able to do part a, using the definitions of a decreasing sequence. For part b,

I know i need to start off with $a_{n}-a_{n+1}$  to obtain

$$\frac{2^n}{n!}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
I'm unsure where to go on from here please could you help

Comment: Use part (a) as stated in the statement of part (b).

Comment: Note that $a_n/a_{n+1}=(2^n/n!)/(2^{n+1}/(n+1)!)=(2^n/n!)*((n+1)!/2^{n+1})=(n+1)/2\geq1$ for all $n\geq 1$.